# Cassandra System.Log shows nodtool tpstats output

Tags: cassandra, log, startup

We have a Docker Cassandra container running 6.8.21. At times when the container is restarted the the Logs show the usual startup activities and all just works well post that.

But on a few occasions we observed that an output similar to that of nodetool tpstats keeps getting printed over and over again. Posting a sample of the output below.

Need help:

1. Why is Cassandra Printing this? Is there some bottleneck that it has hit?
2. What does this log trying to tell?
3. What should be the next steps in our investigation?

Appreciate any help here.

Log:

```
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-08-11 01:33:55,678  StatusLogger.java:174 - 
Pool Name                                       Active        Pending   Backpressure   Delayed      Shared      Stolen      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
AuthzStage                                           0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
LwtStage                                             0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
RequestResponseStage                                 0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
AntiCompactionExecutor                               0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                                     0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
BackgroundIoStage                                    0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor                                 0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                                   0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A             77         0                 0
GossipStage                                          0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
HintsDispatcher                                      0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
InternalResponseStage                                0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter                                  0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A             78         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                                    0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A            203         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory                                0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A             78         0                 0
MigrationStage                                       0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
MiscStage                                            0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator                               0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              1         0                 0
PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0                         0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A             39         0                 0
Repair-Task                                          0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
Sampler                                              0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
SecondaryIndexManagement                             0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
TPC/all                                            N/A            N/A            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A            N/A       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/AUTHENTICATION                               0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              8       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/AUTHORIZATION                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              9       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BACKPRESSURED_MESSAGE_DECODE                 0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BACKPRESSURE_RESCHEDULE                      0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/BACKUP_OPERATION                             0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BATCH_REMOVE                                 0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/BATCH_REPLAY                                 0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BATCH_STORE                                  0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/BATCH_STORE_RESPONSE                         0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BLOCKING_OPERATION_RESTART                   0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/BUFFER_POOL_CLEANUP                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/CLEAN_BACKUPS_OPERATION                      0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/CONTINUOUS_PAGING                            0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/COUNTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK                         0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/EXECUTE_STATEMENT                            0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             38       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/FRAME_DECODE                                 0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/HINT_DISPATCH                                0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/HINT_RESPONSE                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/INCREMENTAL_NODESYNC_MAINTENANCE             0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0           1271       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/LWT_COMMIT                                   0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/LWT_PREPARE                                  0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/LWT_PREPARE_AWAIT_LOCK                       0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/LWT_PROPOSE                                  0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/LWT_PROPOSE_AWAIT_LOCK                       0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/NETWORK_BACKPRESSURE                         0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/NODESYNC_VALIDATION                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/OUTBOUND_FLUSH                               0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/OUTBOUND_SCHEDULED_FLUSH                     0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/PARALLEL_MESSAGE_DECODE                      0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/POPULATE_VIRTUAL_TABLE                       0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_DISK_ASYNC                              0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             36       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_DISK_RETRY                              0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_DISK_WOULD_BLOCK                        0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_INTERNAL                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             13       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_LOCAL                                   0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/READ_RANGE_INTERNAL                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             22       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_RANGE_LOCAL                             0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/READ_RANGE_NODESYNC                          0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/READ_RANGE_REMOTE                            0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/READ_RANGE_RESPONSE                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             22       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_REMOTE                                  0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/READ_RESPONSE                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             13       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_SECONDARY_INDEX                         0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_SPECULATE                               0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_SWITCH_FOR_ITERATOR                     0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/READ_TIMEOUT                                 0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/RESTORE_OPERATION                            0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/SAVE_LOCAL_NODE                              0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              7       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/SAVE_PEER_NODES                              0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/SOLR_ACQUIRE_LOCK                            0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/SOLR_INDEXING                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/SYSTEM_KEYSPACE_ACQUIRE_LOCK                 0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/TIMED_TIMEOUT                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0           2331       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/TIMED_UNKNOWN                                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/TRUNCATE                                     0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/UNKNOWN                                      0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0             49       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/UPDATE_NOTIFICATION                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/VIEW_ACQUIRE_LOCK                            0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_AWAIT_COMMITLOG_SEGMENT                0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_AWAIT_COMMITLOG_SYNC                   0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_DEFRAGMENT                             0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/WRITE_INTERNAL                               0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              3       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_LOCAL                                  0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/WRITE_MEMTABLE_FULL                          0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_REMOTE                                 0              0            N/A       N/A           0           0              0       N/A                 0
TPC/all/WRITE_RESPONSE                               0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0              3       N/A               N/A
TPC/all/WRITE_SWITCH_FOR_MEMTABLE                    0            N/A            N/A       N/A           0           0            372       N/A               N/A
ValidationExecutor                                   0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
ViewBuildExecutor                                    0              0            N/A       N/A         N/A         N/A              0         0                 0
CompactionManager                 0         0
MessagingService                n/a       0/0
Buffer pool size for cached reads: 4.000MiB, for direct reads: 4.000MiB
Cached reads buffer pool BufferPool for long lived buffers: Size-tiered from 4.000KiB to 4.000KiB buffers, using 1024 buffers per slab.
Sub pools:
Buffer size 4.000KiB: 584.000KiB used, 4.000MiB allocated, 1 slabs.
Overflow: 0.000KiB
Direct reads buffer pool BufferPool for temporary buffers: allocated 4.000MiB, used 0.000KiB, overflow 0.000KiB, overflow allocations mean rate 0.000000
Global memtable buffer pool size: onHeap = 3.402KiB, offHeap = 2.029KiB
Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
KeyCache                          0                104857600                      all
RowCache                          0                        0                      all
Table                       Memtable ops,data
system_schema.keyspaces                   0,0
system_schema.hidden_columns                 0,0
system_schema.edges                       0,0
system_schema.views                       0,0
system_schema.columns                     0,0
system_schema.types                       0,0
system_schema.indexes                     0,0
system_schema.vertices                    0,0
system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
system_schema.aggregates                  0,0
system_schema.triggers                    0,0
system_schema.tables                      0,0
system_schema.functions                   0,0
system_auth.roles                       2,262
system_auth.role_members                  0,0
system_auth.role_permissions               1,199
dse_system_local.solr_resources                 0,0
dse_system.encrypted_keys                 0,0
dse_leases.logs                           0,0
dse_leases.leases                         0,0
solr_admin.solr_resources                 0,0
dse_insights.insights_config                 0,0
dse_insights.tokens                       0,0
dse_insights_local.insights_config                 0,0
system_distributed.nodesync_status                 0,0
system_distributed.nodesync_user_validations                 0,0
system_distributed.parent_repair_history                 0,0
system_distributed.repair_history                 0,0
system_distributed.restore_task_state                 0,0
system_distributed.backups                 0,0
system_distributed.backup_task_state                 0,0
system_distributed.view_build_status                 0,0
system_backups.backup_stores                 0,0
system_backups.backup_configurations                 0,0
dse_perf.node_slow_log                    0,0
system_traces.sessions                    0,0
system_traces.events                      0,0
dse_security.digest_tokens                 0,0
dse_security.role_options                 0,0
dse_security.spark_security                 0,0
axone.config_context                      0,0
axone.test_hc                             0,0
axone.config                              0,0
axone.valid_context                       0,0
system.compaction_history               1,254
system.IndexInfo                          0,0
system.repairs                            0,0
system.size_estimates                     0,0
system.paxos                              0,0
system.built_views                        0,0
system.peer_events                        0,0
system.range_xfers                        0,0
system.peers                              0,0
system.batches                            0,0
system.transferred_ranges                 0,0
system.view_builds_in_progress                 0,0
system.local                              0,0
system.sstable_activity                   4,0
system.nodesync_checkpoints                 0,0
system.available_ranges                   0,0
system.prepared_statements               5,655
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sakiv, usually the logs prior to this would give you the clue as to what is happening. In my experience, I've seen when the cluster node(s) gets overloaded, it would cause these to get printed, but it could be other causes too. If you're a paid customer and have a valid subscription, you could contact [support here](https://support.datastax.com/s) to get additional help with your DSE cluster.

Comment: Actually figured that as part of 6.8.17 DSE Cassandra.. it Enables periodic logging of system status (default every 5 minutes, configurable). (DSP-22039)

Comment: BUT, your cluster/node is only running DSE 6.8.16. Do you know how you're getting it?

Comment: Apologies, I specified in-correct version above. Its 6.8.21 that we are on (and not 6.8.16). So this is why we are periodically getting the same. I have corrected the same in the original post as well.

But then Question is how/ what to interpret from this Log? Do you have any document that you could suggest would come handy in interpreting the same?

Thanks for your time - Madhavan.